# Как использовать значение одной таблицы при выборе из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql

Например, есть запрос:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `gifts`.`id`,
            `gifts`.`country`,
            `gifts`.`city`
        FROM
            `gifts` AS `gifts`
    ) AS `t1`
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT
            `users`.`id`,
            `users`.`city`,
            `users`.`country`
        FROM
            `users` AS `users`
        WHERE `users`.`city` = `t1`.`city`
    ) AS `t2` ON `t1`.`country` = `t2`.`country`
```

Тут проблема в этой строчке.

```
WHERE `users`.`city` = `t1`.`city`
```

Понимаю, что можно сделать это условие на уровне JOIN, так:

```
AS `t2` ON `t1`.`country` = `t2`.`country`
AND `t2`.`city` = `t1`.`city`
```

**А можно ли как-то с первым вариантом?**

Comment: Ну Вы же сами видите, что нельзя:)

Comment: Если конкретно Ваша СУБД и её конкретная версия поддерживают LATERAL JOIN / CROSS APPLY - то можно, иначе нельзя.

Comment: @Akina. MySQL 8.0.29, как я понимаю, не поддерживает.

Comment: Прекрасно поддерживает, начиная с 8.0.14. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html

Comment: @Akina, а CROSS APPLY и коррелирующие подзапросы поддерживает?

Comment: Запрос в CROSS APPLY по самому его смыслу - коррелированный. Вообще-то... иначе было бы достаточно CROSS JOIN.